# What does "edge-connected components of graph" means in paper PUNCH?

Tags: graphs

I'm recently trying to study the paper "Graph Partitioning with Natural Cuts": https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/punchTR.pdf

There is a term *edge-connected components* in section 3.1 *Detecting Tiny Cuts*:

> The first pass identifies all **edge-connected components** of the graph using depth-first search.
>   They form a tree T. We make T rooted by choosing as a root the edge-connected component
>   with maximum size, which on road networks typically corresponds to most of the graph. We then
>   traverse T in a top-down fashion. As soon as we enter a subtree S of total size at most U, we
>   contract it into a single vertex...

First, it seems not to mean "connected component" because in section 2 it says:

> To simplify the description of our algorithm, we assume G is connected

And I tried to search this term on Google but only a term *k-edge-connected* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph) found and it seems to mean something different.

Could someone tell me what this term means exactly, please? Thank you!

Comment: It probably just means *connected component*.

Comment: I've not read the paper, but I agree with @YuvalFilmus. Assuming that $G$ is connected does simplify the description, since it means that the first phase does nothing. By the way, note that $1$-edge-connected is the same as connected.

Comment: YuvalFilmus, @DavidRicherby Thanks for your reply! I'm still confused: If it means *connected component*, then DFS should form a forest instead of a tree? And "make T rooted by choosing as a root the edge-connected component with maximum size" seems to suggest that an edge-connected componenet is just a root (node?) of T?